# How to generate a doc file using Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, doc

Using jasper-reports 5.6.1 I am able  to generate the reports in pdf format, but I am not able figure out how to generate a .doc format by using jasper.

```
      byte[] exportReportToPdf = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);
```

is for generating a pdf format file like this is there any similar view class for doc format?

Comment: dose any one know a link to answer my question i searched alot , the word file size is too big knowing that its just a tabular on too many pages like 50 , the file takes too long to open and its like been drawn on the word although i can edit it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try like this

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("myReport.jasper", reportParameters, dataSource);

Exporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));

File exportReportFile = new File("D:\\Temp\\report.docx");

exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(exportReportFile));

exporter.exportReport();
```

HTH

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your solution. It did generate the doc file.

Answer (score 2):

Before executing a report, the JRXML must be compiled in a binary object called a Jasper file(*.jasper). This compilation is done for performance reasons. Jasper files are what you need to ship with your application in order to run the reports. Once the report is compiled it is filled with data from the application. The class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager provides necessary functions to fill the data in the reports.

The report execution is performed by passing a Jasper file and a data source to JasperReports. There are plenty of types of data sources, it's possible to fill a Jasper file from an SQL query, an XML file, a csv file, an HQL (Hibernate Query Language) query, a collection of Java Beans, etc... If you don't find a suitable data source, JasperReports is very flexible and allows you to write your own custom data source.

`JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile( "MasterReport.jasper" , parameters, getDataSource());`

This operation creates a Jasper print file (*.jrprint), which used to either print or export the report.
- See more at: http://blog.manupk.com/2012/11/using-jasper-reports-to-create-reports.html#sthash.rFqV8K4i.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

Try this for docx/word, pdf

```
 try {
  String pathToReports = "/home/test/";
  Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
  JRDataSource jsonDataSource = new JsonDataSource(new File("/home/test/example.json"));
  JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(pathToReports + "main.jrxml");

  JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, jsonDataSource);

  //Export to PDF     
  // JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "/home/test/fileName.pdf");

  //Export to Word
  JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();    
  exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint)); 
  File exportReportFile = new File(fileName + ".docx");    
  exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(exportReportFile));    
  exporter.exportReport();

} catch (Exception e) {}
```